# How to customize Taskbar and Start Layout

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, group-policy, start-menu

In my organization we have a conference room computer that everyone will have access to use.

I am looking to see if I can adjust some layout options on the taskbar and the start menu.

I have already figured out how to adjust the pinned icons on the taskbar and the pined tiles on the start menu for all users that logon. I used https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/configure-windows-10-taskbar and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/customize-and-export-start-layout to do that using the Layoutmodification.xml file.

However, I would also like to make some further adjustments.

On the taskbar I would like to change the search from the search bar to the search icon.

On the start menu I would like to make the following changes [Start Menu Configuration in settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQgK7.png)

So it looks like this [Start Menu Finished](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D21Ex.png)

GPO is currently set to not show recently added files or app/programs and frequently used. I couldn't, however, find GPO options to make the aforementioned adjustments.

I would assume that these adjustments can be made in the Layoutmodification.xml file that sits in "C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell"

However I've looked through

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/customize-and-export-start-layout
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/configure-windows-10-taskbar
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/windows-10-start-layout-options-and-policies
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/customize-start-layout

None of those seemed to provide an answer that the xml file can make these modifications.

If anyone has any idea on how to make these modifications, be it in the xml file or a script, please let me know.

Thank you so much in advance!!